# With JSHint is it possible to mark exported as all?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have a JavaScript file like:

```
function ma(){
   (...)
}
function mb(){
   (...)
}
```

Where ma() and mb() are to be used on another JS file. Usually I use:

```
/* exported ma,mb */
```

But I was wondering if there is a simple way to just mark everything as exported like

```
/* exported * */
```

Does JSHint support this?

Comment: Why not create a top-level object to contain all your functions, instead of exporting a bunch of globals?

Comment: As if it's like a `utility.js`/`helper.js` functions script file?

Comment: Actually those are classes/objects constructor functions for objects that I use throughout my application. Still I believe that is one solution @meagar : set them on a common object and just export that object. But I also have this problem on another file like an utility.js yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible. Here's [the code](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/f4febe8d007869e546ca5bffe4a00edf07a73dc1/src/jshint.js#L650) that runs in JSHint when it encounters an `exported` directive (`nt` is the directive being parsed, `body` is an array of exported identifiers and `exported` is an empty object created previously):

```
if (nt.type === "exported") {
  body.forEach(function (e) {
    exported[e] = true;
  });
}
```

Throughout JSHint you can then find cases where it checks identifiers against the keys in the `exported` object. [For example](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/f4febe8d007869e546ca5bffe4a00edf07a73dc1/src/jshint.js#L4825):

```
if (func["(global)"] && _.has(exported, key))
  return;
```

Based on this there is no way to specify anything other than the actual exported identifiers in the `exported` directive.